# IIS URL rewrite not rewriting a user friendly URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a simple rewrite rule set up using the IIS wizard that should rewrite:

https://example.com/products/detail/ABC-123

to

https://example/com/products/detail.php?sku=ABC-123

The rule is:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*/products/detail/([^/]+)/?$" />
  <conditions>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example.com/products/detail.php?sku={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

When I test the friendly URL on the IIS edit rule -> test pattern dialog box there is a match,

R:0 is https://example.com/products/detail/ABC-123

R:1 is ABC-123.

Yet when I enter the friendly URL into a browser I simply get a 404 error. Unfortunately I cant see what is it actually outputting as the rewritten url, is there a way to find out the result?

Comment: Mistake 1 https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: How is mistake 1 relevant? The match URL ".*/products/detail/([^/]+)/?$" does not have the domain name in it.

Comment: Kindly remind you that `.*/` won't work either and should be removed from the pattern.

Comment: .*/ works fine when tested.

Comment: That's because the test dialog isn't smart enough to tell that you are making common mistakes or not, and it tests regular expressions without contexts. A known issue for more than a decade.

Comment: Thank you for that, useful information. Unfortunately, I just don't have the time to read up on known issues for things I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2">
            <match url="^products/detail/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="products/detail.php?sku={R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I did the following test and it was successful.

Firstly, I created a simple test ASP.NET page locally and named it detail.aspx. I can browse the page correctly by acessing http://localhost/products/detail.aspx?sku=ABC-123.

[image]

Then I created a simple rewrite rule that will rewrite URLs using the following format:

http://localhost/products/detail/ABC-123

to:

http://localhost/products/detail.aspx?sku=ABC-123.

[image]

Finally I tested whether this rule was rewriting the URL correctly. I opened a web browser and requested the following URL:

http://localhost/products/detail/ABC-123

You can see that the rewrite rule on the web server has changed the original URL to detail.aspx and has passed "ABC-123" as the value of the query string parameter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly first time. 